# How do I print predictions in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Ok, I worked through a sample of predicting whether or not a particular product quality was good or bad on Tensorflow.  My final section of code looks like this:

```
# Merge summaries for TensorBoard
merged_summaries = tf.summary.merge_all()

with tf.Session() as sess:

    log_directory = create_log_directory()
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_directory, sess.graph)

    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    for i in range(epochs):
        average_cost = 0
        number_of_batches = int(len(X_train) / batch_size)
        for start, end in zip(range(0, len(X_train), batch_size), range(batch_size, len(X_train), batch_size)):
            feed = {X: X_train[start:end], y: y_train[start:end]}
            sess.run(training_step, feed_dict=feed)
            # Compute average loss
            average_cost += sess.run(cost, feed_dict=feed) / number_of_batches
        if i % epochs_to_print == 0:
            feed = {X: X_test, y: y_test}
            result = sess.run([merged_summaries, accuracy], feed_dict=feed)
            summary = result[0]
            current_accuracy = result[1]
            summary_writer.add_summary(summary, i)
            print("Epoch: {:4d}, average cost = {:.3f}, accuracy = {:.3f}".format(i+1, average_cost, current_accuracy))

    print("Final accuracy = {:.3f}".format(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: X_test, y: y_test})))
```

It puts out a nice set of 10 epochs that top out at 0.527 accuracy, which I assume to be 52.7% accuracy.

```
Saving summaries to tmp/logs/run_32/
Epoch:    1, average cost = 3.300, accuracy = 0.174
Epoch:  101, average cost = 0.685, accuracy = 0.528
Epoch:  201, average cost = 0.682, accuracy = 0.527
Epoch:  301, average cost = 0.680, accuracy = 0.527
Epoch:  401, average cost = 0.680, accuracy = 0.527
Epoch:  501, average cost = 0.679, accuracy = 0.527
Epoch:  601, average cost = 0.679, accuracy = 0.527
Epoch:  701, average cost = 0.679, accuracy = 0.527
Epoch:  801, average cost = 0.679, accuracy = 0.527
Epoch:  901, average cost = 0.679, accuracy = 0.527
Final accuracy = 0.527
```

The problem is that now, I want to feed back in just 1 row of data from (presumably) a numpy array into Tensorflow to get a prediction.  How do I do this?  I assume it follows a pattern that looks like this:

```
input =[1.939501945438227,-1.8459679631200792,1.9134581818982566,-0.6741964131111666,-0.5720868389043996,0.3926397708073837,-2.0777995164924112,0.03405362776450469,0.33621509508483066]
output = <<some function call here>>
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your graph. If you check your `accuracy` node, it may looks like

```
tf.reduce_mean(tf.equal(my_prediction, correct_label))
```

where `correct_label` would be something related to `y_train`,
and `my_prediction` would be some tf node, probably look like `tf.round(...)` depend on your implementation.

What you have to do here is to find that `my_prediction` out, then you can get a prediction using

```
output = sess.run([my_prediction], feed_dict={X: [input]})
```